# Poor formatting in TextMate for multiple lines

Tags: javascript, textmate

I want TextMate to not act like a goober when I create a multi-line code. For example:

```
function foo() {
    return bar.baz()
              .blah() +
           boo.bah();
```

I can manually add in a bunch of extra tabs, but then when I finish the code line (either with a semicolon or curly brace) and return to the next line, it forces my next code to have the same indentation. Like this:

```
function foo() {
    return bar.baz()
              .blah() +
           boo.bah();
           var new_line_starts_here;
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of `return` statement. You need close `Foo` before next code.

Comment: The line `boo.bah();` in this case is supposed to be part of the return statement to `foo()`, so unfortunately your suggestion doesn't help.

Comment: put `}` after `boo.bah();`

Comment: Hmm... nope, I tried your suggestion and that didn't work. It still keeps the indentation on that level.